# An one-time introductory slideshow for all users

Tags: android, android-activity

how do i do it:

**The first time each user visits the Apps screen, a slide show will appear instead of a splash screen which will tell the user about various features.
4 slides will come on the very first run of the app. slides will be changed using the swipe gestures**

the slideshow will appear only for one time after the very first download.

Check this image as a reference: http://main.makeuseoflimited.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/HiLauncher6.png?323f2c

Comment: are You asking for how to make a sliding show or how to show it only the first time the user visit or both?

Comment: i'm asking how to make both as i only know about the splash screen

Comment: like Azael wrote, to get sure the user visit this the first time, use shared preferences. The example is correct. For You slide show, You should use a ViewFlipper. Look here for a good example: http://javatechig.com/android/android-viewflipper-example

Comment: thank you sir...but i want the slides to be changed only by the users not automatically

Comment: ignore the "ImageSlideShow" example, just ,look for the "ViewFlipperSampleActivity", that´s all You need..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is store a Boolean variable inside the app using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) which will determine whether the slideshow has appeared once or not, if so the don't show it again.

For example:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isFirstTime = sp.getBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME, true);

if (isFirstTime) {

        showSlideshow()


    } else {

        // Go to your main activity
        Intent main = new Intent(Start.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(main);
        finish();

    }
```

Don't forget to set **isFirstTime** to **false** once the slideshow has been shown, and store it in the sharedPreferences

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks for the help but i'm looking for bit more information on it

Comment: Ok, I thought you only needed to know how to show it for the first time, in that case someone just mentioned that you should use the [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) class

Comment: yes i checked the link but it's not exactly what m looking for. I want the slides to be changed by the user through swipe gestures.

Comment: Here http://android-er.blogspot.ca/2012/02/implement-swiping-page-effect-using.html